# dynamicly created table Sum total for column in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm just learning jQuery.
I need to create a table dynamicly with jQuery, which works fine. The problem is that I need a sum field, which updates automaticly according to newly added rows.
I succeed in this, but it adds the allready summed value on the new row's value.
Now I added a button, when I hit it once it the sum value is correct, but the seccond time hitting it adds all rows on the result...

Here's my code:

```
  <table id="packagetopack">
        <thead><tr class="titlerow">
            <th style="height:60px;vertical-align: middle">Artikel</th>
            <th style="height:60px;vertical-align: middle"> Menge</th>
            <th style="height:60px;vertical-align: middle"> Volumen</th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
<tr class="totalrow"><td class="totalCol"></td><td class="totalCol"></td><td class="totalCol"></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and jQuery:

```
  $('#mengeneingabe').click(function() {
        $('#packagetab').show();
        var productName;
        productName = $('#selectionbox').val();
        var productQuant;
        productQuant = $('#mengeneingabe').val();
        var productvolume;
        productvolume = $('#volumen').html();
        var volumetotal;
        volumetotal = productvolume * productQuant;
        var result = volumetotal.toFixed(2);
        $('#packagetopack > tbody:last').append('<tr><td class="rowDataSd">'+productName+'</td><td class="rowDataSd">'+productQuant+'</td><td class="rowDataSd">'+result+'</tr>');
    });

    var totals=[0,0,0];
    $('#berechnenbutton').click(function(){

        var $dataRows=$("#packagetopack tr:not('.totalrow, .titlerow')");

        $dataRows.each(function() {
            $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i){
                totals[i]+=parseFloat( $(this).html());
            });
        });
        $("#packagetopack td.totalCol").each(function(i){
            $(this).html("total:"+totals[i]);
        });

    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variale totals should be within the scope of your function, like this:

```
$('#berechnenbutton').click(function(){
    var totals=[0,0,0];
```

This way it is reinitiated every call.